# How to do "--add-modules" with dynamically created layer in JPMS?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I create JPMS layer this way:

```
Configuration cf = parentLayer.configuration().resolveAndBind(moduleFinder, ModuleFinder.of(), moduleNames);
ModuleLayer layer = parentLayer.defineModulesWithOneLoader(cf, parentClassLoader);
```

And I have a problem with adding implementation modules. These implementation modules are ignored by JPMS because classes from these modules are not used anywhere (it is clear, that classes from API modules are used). So, JPMS doesn't add these modules to layer.

As I understand, if I spoke about implementation modules on boot layer, I could use `--add-modules` jvm argument. However, I couldn't find any information how to force JPMS load my module (even if its classes are not used) for dynamically created layers.

Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: What about the `moduleNames` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The effect of `--add-modules` is to add the given modules to the set of root modules.

Configuration#resolveAndBind lets you specify the root modules using the last parameter. You need to ensure the modules you want to load are included in these root modules.

To use all the possible modules in the layer you intend to create, you can use the following:

```java
Set<String> moduleNames = moduleFinder.findAll()
        .stream()
        .map(ModuleReference::descriptor)
        .map(ModuleDescriptor::name)
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
Configuration cf = parentLayer.configuration().resolveAndBind(moduleFinder, ModuleFinder.of(), moduleNames)
```